# umask doesn't work with nohup

Tags: linux, permissions, nohup, umask

It seems that `umask` and `nohup` don't work correctly together.

I did this:

```
$ umask 022
$ nohup java -jar blah.jar &
[1] 12345
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
$ ls -l nohup.out
-rw-------. 1 juser juser 41242 Jun 27 11:07 nohup.out
```

Any idea why? Is it `nohup` that forces 600 ignoring `umask` settings? How can I get `nohup.out` to be created with 644 permissions instead than 600? OK, I can do a `chmod 644 nohup.out`, but I'd prefer a "clean" approach.

My shell is bash, my OS is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU’s implementation of `nohup` [ignores `umask`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html):

> Any `nohup.out` or `$HOME/nohup.out` file created by `nohup` is made readable and writable only to the user, regardless of the current `umask` settings.

This only applies when `nohup` itself creates the file, so you can create `nohup.out` with the appropriate permissions before running `nohup`, and `nohup` will append to it without changing the permissions:

```
umask 022
touch nohup.out
nohup java -jar blah.jar &
```

or even use a redirection to get the shell to create the file for you:

```
umask 022
> nohup.out nohup java -jar blah.jar &
```

Comment: It works also with a `nohup java -jar blah.jar > nohup.out 2>&1 &` Indeed, thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, that’s a nice variant, getting the shell to create the file for you.